# Forbidding Use of Function Contained in Header File

Tags: c++

I have functions stored with a class in a header file that I `#include` in the header of my `Source.cpp` file. The header contains a `date` class, along with relevant constructors, overloaded operators, and methods.

I leverage these functions in some of my class' constructors (for instance, a function to convert a Gregorian calendar day into a Julian day number). However, I can't think of a valid reason to allow the use of a few of these functions *outside* of the header file: they're only useful to the class, after all.

Is there a way for me to make it impossible for these functions to be called outside of the header file, short of making them `private` methods of my class?

**EDIT:** Would the solution also apply to other entities in the class, like `struct`s?

Comment: Do you call these functions from the header file, or is your class implementation only in the .cpp file?

Comment: They are only called in the header file.

Comment: You could make them be private static members, or put them in a `details` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is materially difficult given the nature of header files in C++.  Normally you hide internal details in a nested, anonymous namespace, however that would still be visible to callers who import your .h file.  Thus you only use this trick inside of your .cpp file to make private, non-exported symbols.

The correct thing to do is to place these private class implementations *and* the implementation of your constructor inside of your .cpp file.

```
// foo.h
namespace fooproject {

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(::string s);

 private:
  int converted_s;  // Will be derived from constructor input
}
```

And then:

```
// foo.cpp
namespace {
  // Everything here is visible to this compilation unit only.

  int SecretMagicConverter(::string s) {
    // magic code
  }
}  // namespace

namespace foo_project {

Foo::Foo(::string s) {
  // Here we can plainly call the anonymous namespaced functions above.
  converted_s = SecretMagicConverter(s);
}

}  // namespace foo_project
```

Regarding your follow up, yes, anything in that anonymous namespace is 'normally' usable inside of that .cpp but hidden from any users of your .h file.

Comment: Actually, an anonymous namespace in a header-file is a really bad idea: If more than one TU include it, you get an ODR violation.

Comment: @Deduplicator note, I'm not suggesting he do that, I'm suggesting he use an anonymous namespace inside of his .cpp

Comment: Your first paragraph only states that it would not solve his problem, not that it's UB.